# Redis 6 with TLS

Tags: ssl, redis, tls1.2

I am trying to get Redis 6 (with TLS enabled during compilation, tests after compilation were successful) to work. I am using Lets Encrypt certificate and following configuration:

```
tls-port 63790
tls-cert-file /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.net/cert.pem
tls-key-file /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.net/privkey.pem
tls-ca-cert-dir /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.net/
tls-auth-clients no
tls-protocols "TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3"
```

and this client command from localhost

```
redis-cli --tls --cert /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.net/cert.pem --key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.net/privkey.pem --cacert /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.net/fullchain.pem -h myserver.net -p 63790 -a password
```

Warning: Using a password with '-a' or '-u' option on the command line interface may not be safe.
**Could not connect to Redis at myserver.net:63790: SSL_connect failed: certificate verify failed**

this is output from redis log:
**Error accepting a client connection: error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca**

While I am using openssl client with same certificates, i am able to connect and get ping reply from Redis server

No matter if I change

```
tls-ca-cert-dir /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.net/
```

to

```
tls-ca-cert
```

on server side
or
--cacert /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.net/fullchain.pem to chain.pem on client side
I tried to all versions of

```
tls-protocols ""
```

and change

```
tls-auth-clients no
```

to

```
tls-auth-clients optional
```

but I am still stuck with same error

OpenSSL version is 1.1.1
Redis version is 6.0.8
OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Can you help me to find out reason why is TLS not working, please?

Thank you

Wil

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ahh, SOLVED!
I was putting wrong CA chain. I had to chain root and intermediate certs downloaded from LE website into new file. It may come handy for someone with same problem.

Comment: You should choose your own answer as the accepted answer then.

Comment: the guy forgot the solution

Comment: The fullchain.pem isn't enough. Get the root + intermediate certificates from here and append them into the same pem file: https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/